# Creating arrays from columns in database that I can echo in html

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Im sorry if this has been answered before but I am new to PHP and MySQL and I can't figure this out.

Pretty much every time I alter my code to include an array I get a fatal error. What I am trying to do is display all the data in 3 columns from my table.

I have my site set up where you log in and I store that user's name as a "code" in a session. I have a table that has multiple user form entries that are differentiated by the user's code because in my form, I grab the code as a hidden field and add it to the entry in the table.

So far I have been able to isolate those entries by the users code, in one column I have the sum of all of the user's numerical data and I am able to echo this as a total.

I want the other 3 columns to display all the values in their columns and for each value have a line break in between them. And I am trying to print or echo these results in specific parts on a confirmation page.

I have seen examples with PDO using fetch_all and other examples of storing arrays but I can't seem to figure it out with my existing code.

Here is my existing code:

```
<?php
$user = *****;
$pass = *****;
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT sum(price),part_number,location,price FROM products WHERE code = :usercode");
$stmt->bindParam(':usercode', $_SESSION['MM_Username']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

?>
```

And here is where I want to display the results:

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="7" width="100%">
<tbody>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $user['part_number']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
  <td><?php echo $user['location']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
  <td><?php echo $user['price']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
  <td><?php echo "Total:",  $user['sum(price)']; ?><br></td><!--this is ok-->

</tr>


 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="7" width="100%">
<tbody>
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
     while($user = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
      <tr>
       <td><? echo $user['part_number']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
       <td><? echo $user['location']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
       <td><? echo $user['price']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
       <td><? echo "Total:",  $user['sum(price)']; ?><br></td><!--this is ok-->

      </tr>
    }

    }

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have that IF statement already in my initial PDO, displaying the results isnt the problem, displaying an array of results in the table is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your question that jumped out at me.

- It looks like you're attempting to display both raw data (each row) and aggregate data (the sum of prices). It can be simpler to fetch the information separately instead of in the same request.
- You had mentioned fetch_all in PDO, but the method is fetchAll.
- Instead of working with PDO within the HTML (like iterating through while calling `fetch`), write code so that you're simply iterating over an array.
- Based on your description of the problem, it sounds like you want to separate the total price from the raw data, so you can reduce your table down to three columns and use the table footer to show the total price.

Based on those, I have the following solution that

- Separates the calls to get data into descriptive functions
- Use `money_format` to better display prices
- Removes any database-specific manipulation from the view itself.

```
<?php

function getTotalPriceForUser(PDO $database_handler, $user_code)
{
    // If no rows are returned, COALESCE is used so that we can specify a default
    // value. In this particular case, if there aren't any products that would
    // match, we'd still get a result with a value of 0.
    $sql = 'SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) FROM products WHERE code = ?';
    $stmt = $database_handler->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($user_code));

    // This fetches the first row of the result; the result is given as an array with numerical keys.
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    // [0] refers to the first column
    return $result[0];
}

function getProductsForUser(PDO $database_handler, $user_code)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT part_number, location, price FROM products WHERE code = ?';
    $stmt = $database_handler->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($user_code));

    // fetchAll returns all rows, with each row being an associative array (where part_number, location and price are the keys)
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// Set up the database information    
$user = '*****';
$pass = '*****';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', $user, $pass);

// money_format to use the below money formatting; this makes sure there's a dollar sign to represent USD, for example
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');

// Store $_SESSION['MM_Username'] in a local variable
$user_code = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

// Get the list of products associated with this user code
$products = getProductsForUser($dbh, $user_code);

// Get the total cost of the products
$total_cost = getTotalPriceForUser($dbh, $user_code);

?>
<table style="margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="7" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right" colspan="2">Total:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid #999"><?= money_format('%.2n', $total_cost) ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $product['part_number'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $product['location'] ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: right"><?= money_format('%.2n', $product['price']) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change to this

```
<? echo
```

to

```
<?php echo
```

Comment: I added this, still need to get the table to echo all column values though.

Comment: @holodout you will need to either do a foreach loop like below or a for loop like the 2nd comment below, just make sure that you follow how I did the echo statement.

Comment: @holodout I added another answer.

Comment: I tried adding that foreach code below to the end of my PHP and it gave me a fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
...
$keys = array_keys($user);
foreach ($keys as $k) :
?>
    <td><?= $user[$k]?></td>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: This gives me a fatal error. And is there supposed to be a print or echo in there somewhere in the table? And how do I differentiate which array would display?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /home/onlyaskf/www/www/_dev/confirmation.php on line 130

Comment: Also, I noticed in your answer that there are syntax errors. And how does $user[$k] know which column to echo?

Comment: did you put colon after foreach? According to manual, the definition of array_key function is: Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tbody>
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
   while($user = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $user['part_number']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
   <td><?php echo $user['location']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
   <td><?php echo $user['price']; ?></td><!--all column values-->
   <td><?php echo "Total:",  $user['sum(price)']; ?><br></td><!--this is ok-->

  </tr>
}

}

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont understand how moving that IF statement from my PHP code into the table helps in displaying an array of values for 'part_number' 'location' and 'price'

Comment: I think the main thing to take from this is that you need to have some sort of loop to display the information. There are 10 different ways to bring in the information from your SELECT statement to iterate on to the page. Your main question was why is it not showing and I know that all of us have answer that question for you so please consider giving us a positive feedback

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear and i apologize but getting the information to display is not the problem I was having, getting all of the information from my columns where there are multiple entries is what I was having problems with. Each column has at least 5 or so rows that I want to display in my table but I am only getting the first entry to show up instead of ALL of them. And I would upvote the comments but it wont let me because I dont have enough reputation.